# How to set #+STARTUP: content globally in .emacs?

Tags: org-mode

I want to change the default behavior of org-mode to show all headings when opening a org file. Per file this is possible with `#+STARTUP: content`. Unfortunately I can't manage to set this globally in my .emacs.

I am aware of the [corresponding manual entry](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html) but I can't get it to work. `(setq org-startup-folded "content")` has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: It's

```
(setq org-startup-folded 'content)
```

Rather than the string `"content"`, it needs to be the *symbol* `'content`.